# why we put @ before using resources in android xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout

Why put `@` in xml file of android to access some resources?

```
<android:background="@drawable/coloreffect">
```

Comment: because that's how the syntax was defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to differentiate normal strings and string referred to resources.
For example when you write
`android:background="resource name without @"`

then it act as static value it does not bind from your resources.

Answer (score 2):

> why put before @ in xml file of android to access some resources?

That is to distinguish a reference to a resource from other things.

For example, not only can you have `android:background="@drawable/coloreffect"`, but you can have `android:background="#ffff0000"` to refer to a specific color. Not only can a `TextView` have `android:text="@string/foo"`, but it can have `android:text="Foo"`, for a hard-coded string. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The special character `@` is used to indicate that the following string will reference a resource file.

If you don't put it then `drawable/coloreffect` is interpreted as a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Android follows different syntax for referring to resources, styles etc.

Resources can be referenced from resources using a special XML syntax, such as @drawable/myimage

To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (@), use a question-mark (?), and the resource type portion is optional.

For more details https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Hope this helps.